# postgresql-contrib-14 missing

Tags: postgresql

Now that postgresql 15 is newly released, I'm scrambling to lock my many servers at 14.

Does anyone know where the postgresql-contrib-14 package may be (Ubuntu Server 22.04)?

There's a postgresql-contrib, but it wants to upgrade/install postgresql 15.

Thanks,
rik.

Comment: Is there a reason you need postgresql-contrib?  I just did a search on 22.04 and there *are* no PostgreSQL 15 packages in the 22.04 repositories, so where are you finding PostgreSQL 15?  Are you using an external repository or something?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the version specific postgresql-contrib files went away around postgresql 10. postgresql-contrib-xx functionality has been rolled into the postgresql-xx package itself.

I don't think that postgresql-contrib is a safe package to keep around.  If you install it and apt-get upgrade, it will try to install the latest version of postgresql proper, **regardless** of the version you are currently running.

Answer (score 0):

Please try postgresql14-contrib as key word.

In Rhel I install like this

yum install postgresql14-contrib